# OmniSwitch 6400 Port information

Tags: networking, switch

I'm trying to find out how can I know what equipament is connected to a specific port on a OmniSwitch 6400 Switch.
Anyone knows if it's possible to know the IP and/or MAC Address of the equipamentos connected to the different Ports on the switch

Answer (score 0):

According to the following documentation,  [OmniSwitch AOS Release 6.4.5 CLI Reference Guide](http://enterprise.alcatel-lucent.com/docs/?id=22594), the command that would provide you MAC addresses systems directly connected to the Omniswitch 6400 is found in Chapter 12, page 15.  The command is `show mac-address-table`.  From their example:

```
-> show mac-address-table
Legend: Mac Address: * = address not valid

Domain   Vlan/SrvcId  Mac Address         Type      Protocol  Operation  Interface 
--------+-----------+------------------+----------+---------+----------+-----------
   VLAN   1          00:00:00:00:00:01   learned    0800      bridging     8/1
   VLAN   1          00:d0:95:6a:73:9a   learned    aaaa0003  bridging   10/23

Total number of Valid MAC addresses above = 2
```

In a standard MAC address, which is 48 bits long, the first 6 hexadecimal digits from the left, is the **OUI** or the **O***rganizationally* **U***nique*  **I***dentifier* of the hardware, insofar as the MAC address hasn't been intentionally changed by the user.

In the above example, the first system shown to be on port 8/1, clearly looks like a test entry.  00:00:00 is in fact registered to Xerox, whose [PARC division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerox_PARC) invented Ethernet. The second entry's OUI is registered to `Alcatel-Lucent, Enterprise Business Group` according to [one](http://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html) of the [many web-based OUI lookup tools](http://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=OUI%20Lookup%20Tools&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=P8-nUf30JLK60AHjtIHgDQ).